# Compile Sweave files with LuaTeX

Tags: r, tex, sweave

I prefer LuaTeX over XeTeX mainly because of the greater support of the package `microtype`. Therefore, I would like to include my results from R in a document typeset with LuaTeX, through a Sweave file - which I prefer over Rmarkdown for the easier control over the TeX packages and settings.

I am using RStudio, which does not provide LuaTeX among the options to compile the Sweave files.
However, I have seen a 4 y.o. RStudio-support-community [webpage](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200637578-lualatex), which provides a solution, but I still have a few doubts: does it suffices to enter `Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX = "LuaLaTeX")` in the R console? 
Moreover, is there any better solution? And does anyone know when RStudio is going to make the LuaTeX option available from the setting menu - since the pair Sweave-LuaTeX seems to already work pretty well together?

Comment: seems that is still the way [rstudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532257-Customizing-LaTeX-Options) advise to do it. Probably better to ask at https://community.rstudio.com/ , if any changes are planned

Comment: @user20650 alright, thanks.

Comment: If your concern is about `microtype`, why not just use `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Hugh right question: I want to use OTFs and TTFs